# How should I get a type from an IVariable in Java/Eclipse Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a debug tool for Eclipse and I am unsure if the solution I created is appropriate. I am using [this](http://jarvis.cs.ucdavis.edu/code_essence/functions/1397196) code from IBM as example.

So far I wrote the following code (which is functional):

```
IVariable variable = stackVariables[i];

if(isPrimitiveType(variable)){
    return true;
}

private boolean isPrimitiveType(IVariable variable){
    try {
        return primitiveTypes().contains(variable.getReferenceTypeName());
    } catch (DebugException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private HashSet<String> primitiveTypes(){
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(8);
    set.add("short");
    set.add("int");
    set.add("long");
    set.add("float");
    set.add("double");
    set.add("boolean");
    set.add("byte");
    set.add("char");
    return set;
}
```

I really don't like the idea of checking for a part of a String using contains method. However, I can't really see a better option. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the IVariable is an instance of IJavaVariable you can look at the JNI type signature or get the IJavaType.